# can we expect a bounded approximate identity in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$, whose Fourier transform at particular point is zero?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, banach-algebras

Let $\phi:\mathbb R \to \mathbb C$ be a function; and define 
$$\phi_{t}(x):=\frac{1}{t}\phi (x/t), (t>0).$$

We let, $\phi\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ then $\phi_{t}\in L^{1}(\mathbb R);$ in fact, we have,  $\|\phi \|_{L^{1}}= \|\phi_{t}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)}.$

We also assume that, $\hat{\phi}(0)=1= \int_{\mathbb R} \phi(x) dx;$ then $\{\phi_{t}\}_{t>0}$ forms a bounded approximate identity in $L^{1}(\mathbb R);$   that is, 
if $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R)$, then $\|f\ast \phi_{t}- f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \to 0$ as $t\to 0.$

**My Question is**: Fix $\xi_{0}\in \mathbb R.$ Then can we expect to find a sequence $\{k_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda >0} \subset L^{1}(\mathbb R);$ with the following properties:
(1) $\hat{k_{\lambda}} (\xi_{0}) =0,$  for all $\lambda $, (2) $\|k_{\lambda}\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \leq C$ for all $\lambda$ and $C$ is some constant, (3)  If $f\in L^{1}(\mathbb R),$ then 
$\|f\ast k_{\lambda} - f\|_{L^{1}(\mathbb R)} \to 0$ as $\lambda \to 0$ (or $\lambda \to \infty$ , depending on the choice of $k_{\lambda}$).

(Bit Roughly, problem states that, can we expect a bounded approximate identity in $L^{1}(\mathbb R)$, whose Fourier transform at particular point is zero. )

**Edit**: If I assume $\hat{f}(\xi_{0})=0$, then what can we say in in the above problem.( In view of the following remark)

Thanks,

Comment: No, because (3) implies that $\|\widehat{f}\widehat{k}-\widehat{f}\|_{\infty}\to 0$, which will now fail at $\xi_0$ (unless $\widehat{f}(\xi_0)=0$).

Comment: @ChristianRemling; thanks, If I additionally assume, $\hat{f}(\xi_{0})=0,$ then can we expect ?

Comment: Off the top of my head I'd say this sounds like it should work.